# Openart Order via PayPal Pending

Tags: opencart

I have an Opencart site, basically I have PayPal payment (sandbox mode), but when I try to pay it, it is always pending on admin even though on Paypal it is successfully paid,

here is my error log IPN

> 2018-02-09 7:28:38 - PP_STANDARD :: IPN REQUEST:
>   cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=253.00&invoice=44+Mark+Anthony+Bautista&protection_eligibility=Eligible&item_number1=Product+5&item_number2=&payer_id=DMF8T4TAAWKCJ&payment_date=23%3A28%3A25+Feb+08%2C+2018+PST&option_name2_1=Personalise&option_selection1_1=White&payment_status=Pending&charset=windows-1252&first_name=test¬ify_version=3.8&custom=44&payer_status=verified&business=jo-facilitator%40joyceorena.com&num_cart_items=2&verify_sign=ARhXYj9-geVZC-qz8Pfn8CjmemnhAJsEwj0adsLaEG3Lyj4S9ke0vGla&payer_email=jo-buyer%40joyceorena.com&option_name1_1=Color&txn_id=24C45780W2261325L&payment_type=instant&option_selection2_1=Size+Personalisation&last_name=buyer&item_name1=Cashmere+Saint+Laurent&receiver_email=jo-facilitator%40joyceorena.com&item_name2=Shipping%2C+Handling%2C+Discounts+%26+Taxes&quantity1=1&quantity2=1&receiver_id=4N8KBNVHLZE8Y&pending_reason=multi_currency&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=203.00&mc_currency=PHP&mc_gross_2=50.00&residence_country=US&test_ipn=1&transaction_subject=&payment_gross=&ipn_track_id=1b30468ca8807
>   2018-02-09 7:28:38 - PP_STANDARD :: IPN RESPONSE: VERIFIED

Can someone tell me what is missing ?

Opencart Version 2.2.0.0

Paypal Standard Payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the payment sent over in Peso but your merchant account does not having Peso in accepted currencies. You need to add Peso currencies in your merchant account.

Look at the pending_reason=multi_currency. This somehow shows you that you are not holding the currencies that the payment was sent to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already figure it out! It is working now.